# Open Admin bar "Visit site" in a new window

Tags: admin-bar

Is it possible to create a filter to make in sort that the link in the admin bar to open in a new window. I know that the right-click -> open in a new tab is a common use for us programmers but for the client who use it, it could be great to open in a new tab.

[image]

Hope to find a solution without changing the core file "admin-bar.php" so it won't get overwrite on any WP's updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually easily done. I just adapted the code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47927/47733)

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'customize_my_wp_admin_bar', 80 );
function customize_my_wp_admin_bar( $wp_admin_bar ) {

    //Get a reference to the view-site node to modify.
    $node = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('view-site');

    //Change target
    $node->meta['target'] = '_blank';

    //Update Node.
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($node);

}
```

To change any other item in the menu bar you just need to find the id of the item to change and adapt `get_node`. Look in `/wp-includes/admin-bar.php` for the id or have a look at the css classes of the output.

Comment: Nice it works. Just like that, is it possible to add this action on the parent. The one with the little house icon ?

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer. You are looking for id `site-name` in `wp-includes/admin-bar.php:285`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For people like me wondering why we doesn't do something like `$wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'view-site' );` before doing the `add_node` : it's because the wordpress code do multiple checks and only update metadata if possible. See the source of the `add_node` function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_admin_bar/add_node/#source)