# Set anchor target for admin bar nodes

Tags: admin-bar

I'm using the snippet from [Open Admin bar "Visit site" in a new window](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147778/open-admin-bar-visit-site-in-a-new-window#answers) which works perfectly on the node I specify.

I need to adapt this to include all of the sub-nodes, which are dynamically created, but follow this logic:

```
node
 node_1
  node_1_view
  node_1_another
  node_1_andanother
 node_2
  node_2_view
  etc
 node_3
 etc
```

This gets additions following the same sequence.

**How can I modify the code to set the target for all of these node?**

Comment: What do you mean by nodes? Posts? Menu items?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [`$wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_nodes) to get all toolbar nodes, then loop them through and modify the right nodes as needed. Something along these lines,

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'customize_my_wp_admin_bar', 80 );
function customize_my_wp_admin_bar( $wp_admin_bar ) {
  $all_toolbar_nodes = $wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();

  if ( ! $all_toolbar_nodes ) {
    return;
  }

  foreach ( $all_toolbar_nodes as $node ) {
    // Skip nodes you don't want to edit
    if ( ! $some_logic ) {
      continue;
    }
    //Change target
    $node->meta['target'] = '_blank';
    //Update Node.
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($node);    
  }

}
```

I can't remember what properties `$node` has, but I guess there's some sort of `parent` property that you can use in the `if` statement to skip the wrong ones.